# making a variable with a variable?

Tags: bash

Could anyone explain me how do i make $2 & $3 these num1 & num2 so i can change the starting and ending number of my ping formula? without changing anything in my formula.

```
num1=1
num2=255

until [ -z $1 ] 

  case in "$1" in 

               a) $2="$num1"
                  $3="$num2" ;;
   [0-9]*-[0-9]*) $num1=${1%-*} 
                  $num2=${1#*-}

  esac
done

for ip in $(seq $num1 $num2); do
  ping -c 1 -w 1 192.168.1.$ip>/dev/null; && eho "192.168.1.$ip is up" ||:;
done
```

Comment: You have a separate error in your final `for` loop. Commands should be terminated with either `;` or `&&/||`, not both. The correct line would be `ping ... > /dev/null && echo "..." || :`. (Although there is no need for the final `|| :` and it could be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Look up *indirection* in the bash manual. Obscurely, `!` introduces variable indirection.

```
$ a=hello
$ var=a
$ echo ${!var}
hello
```

*Edit*

```
num1=1
num2=255
case in "$1" in 
a)
    num1=$2;
    num2=$3
    ;;
[0-9]*-[0-9]*)
    num1=${1%-*} 
    num2=${1#*-}
    ;;
esac

for ip in $(seq $num1 $num2); do
    ping -c 1 -w 1 192.168.1.$ip>/dev/null && echo "192.168.1.$ip is up" ||:;
done
```

Comment: i dont want to be rude but is is possible to try it with my example without changing the formula?

Comment: ah! i'm sorry i found my solution, thank you very much bobbogo